# Método eficiente para comparar listas

Tags: java, desempenho, lista

Estou com um problema em que preciso comparar Strings e definir sua proximidade.

O problema é que tenho uma lista com 21 mil registros e preciso comparar todos, um com o outro, o que daria uma complexidade quadrática e no total seriam 21mil*21mil comparações, o que não leva pouco tempo. Preciso fazer isso de modo mais rápido e prático.

Eu estou inserindo esses registros num banco de dados para facilitar a manipulação mas faço algumas alterações e filtros nele através da programação em Java, antes de inserir. Abaixo segue um trecho do código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < limite; j++) {

               if (searchForItem(listaoComp, listao.get(j).id, listao.get(i).id)) {

                    naoInsere++;
                } else {

                    insere++;

                   listaoComp.add(new Comparacao(listao.get(i).id, listao.get(j).id));
               }
                total++;
            }

        }
```

**Basicamente, estou fazendo a verificação quadrática. Como isso acontece, por exemplo, estou comparando os registros (0,1) e (1,0) e inserindo eles na lista. No meu caso, registros assim significam a mesma coisa e não precisam estar os dois na lista então o searchForItem verifica antes de inserir (1,0) se já existe (0,1) na lista. O searchForItem faz isso.** Esse método vai ficando pior ao longo da execução do código pois a lista vai aumentando consideravelmente.

Para contextualiza-los, tenho uma lista de princípios ativos de remédios (id e nome) que formam a classe Princípio, a qual o listão é uma lista deste objeto.
 `List<Principio> listao = new ArrayList<Principio>();`

Já a listaoComp é uma lista de Comparacao.

Na classe Comparacao, guardo os ids dos principios ativos comparados e sua proximidade, por exemplo

```
new Comparacao(1, 2, 98.5);
```

Ah, e a variável *limite* dentro dos For's indicam o tamanho do listao.

```
int limite = listao.size()
```

Como dito anteriormente, estou comparando todos os ids duas vezes, por exemplo
0 - 0 /
0 - 1 /
0 - 2 /
1 - 0 /
1 - 1 /
1 - 2 /
2 - 0 /
2 - 1 /
2 - 2

O searchForItem procura na listaoComp se já existe o registro 0 - 1 antes de inserir o 1 - 0, entende?

Estava tentando usar o Stream Parallels do Java 8 mas não sei utilizar a ferramenta com direito e não consegui montar esta lógica nos filters. (Não sei nem se é ai mesmo que devo montar as condições.)

A minha dúvida é se alguém já passou por algo parecido e tem algum algorítimo que não seja quadrático para fazer isso e se poderiam me indicar uma direção.

Comment: Não entendi esse `searchForItem` e nem essa classe `Comparacao`. O tipo de `listao` é `List<String>`? O que é `listaoComp`?

Comment: Não seria mais simples criar uma classe que represente seu objeto, implementar nela os métodos `hashcode` e `equals` com a sua definição de "igual" e, então, armazená-los em um `Set`?

Comment: Quantos elementos você quer ter no `listaoComp` como resultado? Do jeito que você descreve seu problema, não ficou claro se seriam 21.000, se seriam 441.000.000, se seriam 210.000.000 ou se seria outra coisa.

Comment: Após entender o seu problema, a solução deve ser simples, e a menos que você de fato esteja precisando de um número quadrático de resultados no seu `listaoComp`, deve existir uma solução simples que seja *O(n log n)* ou *O(n)*, provavelmente usando um `Set` ou um `Map`. O problema é que está difícil entender o que é que você está tentando fazer exatamente. Coloque na sua pergunta o código de `searchForItem` e de `Comparacao` que deve ficar mais fácil. E descreva o tipo de `listao` (dado esse `.id`, então não é `String`, mas então não sei o que é).

Comment: destaquei no texto que escrevi o que o searchForItem faz. A classe Comparação guarda os ids dos objetos comparados e o valor de proximidade entre eles. No caso a classe possui tres atributos: id1, id2 e nome. Esses ids sao referentes as posições da lista dos objetos que estou verificando. O listao guarda um objeto que será comparado. Não sei dizer o número exato de elementos mas 441 milhoes seriam todas as possíveis comparações, creio que o número correto seria em torno de 50~52%.

Comment: Ok irei alterar a pergunta e aguardo o feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem a pretenção de ser a solução mais performatica para o seu caso. Mas se você não quer comparar os items iguais (1 : 1) ou seus inversos (1 : 0 e 0 : 1) você poderia simplesmente alterar o seu laço interno para começar na posição `i + 1`

```
for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = (i + 1) ; j < lista.size(); j++) {
      // Como aqui você já ignora os indices iguais ou inversos..
      // seria simplesmente adicionar as comparações.
      listaComp.add(new Comparacao(...));
    }
}
```

Dessa forma você ira comparar os indices.. [0,1; 0,2; ...1,2; 1,3... 2,3 ...n, n+1...]

Análisando um exemplo de 10 items, um algoritmo de tempo de execução quadratico (n²) como o seu, teria 100 iterações. Já, com esta simples alteração, isso cairia para 45 iterações. Então, estrapolando para o seu caso de 21mil registros, de 441.000.000, vai pra <s>198.450.000</s> 220.489.500 iterações.